# How to get the real execution time of a Pipeline and the duration time of start up of the VMs of a Dataflow Job

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow, apache-beam

I want to get both duration times: the exact time of start up of the Virtual Machines deployed in Compute Engine, and the real execution time of the Pipeline, when a Dataflow Job ends (which is much less than the elapse time showed by the Job in the Dataflow website)

I need to get these duration times from Java, and maybe if I can get these values directly from Google Cloud website will be fine also.

Comment: Do you want to do this for every pipeline you run? You can add a distribution metric to aggregate timestamps on the first and last pardo's of your pipeline. If you just want an estimate, you could run an empty pipeline (e.g. `Create([1]) | Map(lamba x: x)`), and see how long it takes to run. Any special reason why you need to do this?

Comment: +1 to Pablo; also, "startup time of the VMs" is not well-defined. Number of VMs changes over time, so some might be started and stopped while the job runs; even for the initial number of VMs, they get started in parallel and each VM starts up at a different time; there are different points in the life of a VM when you could consider it "started": e.g. are you interested in "the VM is powered on", "it has booted the OS", or "it has started the Dataflow worker process", etc? Shutdown is similarly vague and parallel and includes more than just shutting down VMs. Knowing your use case would help.