# How to find total execution time taken for each step in Google DataFlow using java sdk

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am running DataFlow job in Google cloud platform using Apache-beam-2.3.0. Each dataFlow job has 5 steps. I want to track time taken to complete each steps in a job using java SDK

```
Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
PCollection<String> csv = pipeline.apply(transform1);
csv.apply(transform2);
}

pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();
```

How to measure the time taken to complete each step in a job using `PipelineResult`

Comment: Any inputs here is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [queryMetrics](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.3.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/metrics/MetricResults.html) with [PipelineResult](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.3.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/PipelineResult.html) to see metrics at the step level. For example:

```
Pipeline p = ...;
 p.apply("create1", Create.of("hello")).apply("myStepName1", ParDo.of(new SomeDoFn()));
 p.apply("create2", Create.of("world")).apply("myStepName2", ParDo.of(new SomeDoFn()));
 PipelineResult result = p.run();
 MetricResults metrics = result.metrics();
 MetricQueryResults metricResults = metrics.queryMetrics(new MetricsFilter.Builder()
     .addNameFilter("my-counter")
     .addStepFilter("myStepName1").addStepFilter("myStepName2")
     .build());
 Iterable<MetricResult<Long>> counters = metricResults.counters();
 // counters should contain the value of my-counter reported from each of the ParDo
 // applications.
```

In this case, instead of a counter you could define a [distribution metric](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.3.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/metrics/Metrics.html#distribution-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-) as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45122068/how-to-get-the-real-execution-time-of-a-pipeline-and-the-duration-time-of-start). Some examples in this [link](https://www.javatips.net/api/beam-master/sdks/java/core/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/metrics/MetricsTest.java).